# Overlaying a rasterfile .tiff into google map

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geotiff

I have a raster file(.tiff) and I want to Overlay it into specific lat,long. and like a real map it be possible to zoom-in and zoom-out and so on.

I have found [this page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image-overlay)
but it dose not work on my local computer. 
the second question is how to insert my raster instead of the picture ?

Comment: It worked for me locally, but only once I put the `http:` protocol in front of the URL at `return ['//www.gstatic.com/io2010maps/tiles/5/L2_'`

Comment: yeap thats right. thx